# Counter as variable in for-in-loops

Tags: variables, swift, constants, declaration, for-in-loop

When normally using a for-in-loop, the counter (in this case `number`) is a constant in each iteration:

```
for number in 1...10 {
    // do something
}
```

This means I cannot change `number` in the loop:

```
for number in 1...10 {
    if number == 5 {
        ++number
    }
}

// doesn't compile, since the prefix operator '++' can't be performed on the constant 'number'
```

Is there a way to declare `number` as a variable, without declaring it before the loop, or using a normal for-loop (with initialization, condition and increment)?

Comment: Modifying the iterator of a `for` is usually considered bad code. `for in` has no iterator, `number` is not an iterator. Its value doesn't affect the loop in any way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To understand why `i` can’t be mutable involves knowing what `for…in` is shorthand for.  `for i in 0..<10` is expanded by the compiler to the following:

```
var g = (0..<10).generate()
while let i = g.next() {
    // use i
}
```

Every time around the loop, `i` is a freshly declared variable, the value of unwrapping the next result from calling `next` on the generator.

Now, that `while` *can* be written like this:

```
while var i = g.next() {
    // here you _can_ increment i:
    if i == 5 { ++i }
}
```

but of course, it wouldn’t help – `g.next()` is still going to generate a 5 next time around the loop.  The increment in the body was pointless.

Presumably for this reason, `for…in` doesn’t support the same `var` syntax for declaring it’s loop counter – it would be very confusing if you didn’t realize how it worked.

(unlike with `where`, where you can see what is going on – the `var` functionality is occasionally useful, similarly to how `func f(var i)` can be).

If what you want is to skip certain iterations of the loop, your better bet (without resorting to C-style `for` or `while`) is to use a generator that skips the relevant values:

```
// iterate over every other integer
for i in 0.stride(to: 10, by: 2) { print(i) }

// skip a specific number
for i in (0..<10).filter({ $0 != 5 }) { print(i) }

let a = ["one","two","three","four"]

// ok so this one’s a bit convoluted...
let everyOther = a.enumerate().filter { $0.0 % 2 == 0 }.map { $0.1 }.lazy

for s in everyOther {
    print(s)
}
```

Comment: You simply give great answers!

Comment: Swift 3 allows var in for...in loops. However, it is overwritten on each turn.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "no", and that's a good thing. Otherwise, a grossly confusing behavior like this would be possible:

```
for number in 1...10 {
    if number == 5 {
        // This does not work
        number = 5000
    }
    println(number)
}
```

Imagine the confusion of someone looking at the number 5000 in the output of a loop that is supposedly bound to a range of 1 though 10, inclusive.

Moreover, what would Swift pick as the next value of 5000? Should it stop? Should it continue to the next number in the range before the assignment? Should it throw an exception on out-of-range assignment? All three choices have some validity to them, so there is no clear winner.

To avoid situations like that, Swift designers made loop variables in range loops immutable.

Comment: It's really helpful to think about `for in` as a completely different structure that a common `for` loop. `number` is not an iterator, it is a parameter of a function/block that is called in every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Update **Swift 5**

```
for var i in 0...10 {
    print(i)
    i+=1
}
```